# Firefox shows blank page, method with @BeforeTest annotation is not being executed

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

FireFox is opened but method with @BeforeTest Annotation is not being executed where it is written to read the properties field to get URL and read excel sheet to get data for test cases.

In eclipse I can see the other methods with @Test annotation.

Comment: How do you start the tests? How does the test code look like? Have you tried to debug the code? How do you know that @BeforeTest is not executed?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, whenever you execute methods which having annotation @test - it will start execution from @BeforeClass @BeforeMethod.

Please check the code which you have written executing by putting that code into one method, if it works fine then it will automatically work with the @BeforeMethod annotation as well.

Regards,
Sravan

Answer (score 0):

Method with @BeforeTest annotation was not marked under the group hence it was not being executed. I added the group and it ran like magic. Thanks all!!!